# Boost thread Overhead

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, threadpool, boost-thread

I found that boost thread overhead has three order of magnitude timing overhead in the following simple program. Is there anyway to reduce this overhead and speedup the `fooThread()` call ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>
typedef uint64_t tick_t;
#define rdtscll(val) do { \
    unsigned int __a,__d; \
    __asm__ __volatile__("rdtsc" : "=a" (__a), "=d" (__d)); \
        (val) = ((unsigned long long)__a) | (((unsigned long long)__d)<<32); \
    } while(0)


class baseClass {
 public:
   void foo(){
             //Do nothing 
        }
       void threadFoo(){
          threadObjOne = boost::thread(&baseClass::foo, this);
              threadObjOne.join();
   }

 private:
   boost::thread threadObjOne;
 };

int main(){
   std::cout<< "main startup"<<std::endl; 
   baseClass baseObj; 
   tick_t startTime,endTime;
       rdtscll(startTime);
   baseObj.foo();
   rdtscll(endTime);
   std::cout<<"native foo() call takes "<< endTime-startTime <<" clock cycles"<<std::endl;
   rdtscll(startTime);
   baseObj.threadFoo();
       rdtscll(endTime);
       std::cout<<"Thread foo() call takes "<< endTime-startTime <<" clock cycles"<<std::endl;  
  }
```

You can compile it with `g++ -lboost_thread-mt main.cpp` and here is the sample output in my machine:

```
main startup
native foo() call takes 2187 clock cycles
Thread foo() call takes 29630434 clock cycles
```

Comment: Call boost thread first, native last and tell us the results. It just looks as if you had a context switch ~30 mln cycles at ~3 GHz is roughly 10 ms - a nice resemblance of time granularity.

Comment: Performance drops to 4 order of magnitude :  main startup
Thread foo() call takes 13418779 clock cycles
native foo() call takes 2197 clock cycles

Comment: We know there is a cost in starting threads. You need to ask the OS for stack space set up a whole set of other stuff. As Lyth said 10ms is not that bad. Thus orders of magnitude are not relevant as you don't create a thread each time you want to run a function in parallel. The way to speed this up is create one thread then call foo() a billion times and compare it the cost with calling it normally a billion times. The cost of thread set up is then insignificant.

Comment: I see your points Loki. However, this negligible thread overhead will kill application parallel processing because in my case each parallel function body is very simple. Therefore, calling functions sequentially beats multi-threading implementation. If there is no other way to reduce this overhead, I think I should forget about multi-threading.

Comment: Take a look to thread pools in that case, that should reduce the creation overhead to only one call.

Comment: Yes using threading incorrectly will usually slow down an application rather than speed it up. But that does not preclude us trying to get you to use it correctly and get a speed increase. The point is **NOT** to start a new thread for each function. You only want to start a small number of threads anyway (The exact number varies but (1.5 -> 2)*<cpu count> is a good starting point). Then you divide your functions across each of the threads. Thus each thread will perform a set of functions in sequence. By using a thread pull (as suggested by @KillianDS) you dynamically distribute the load.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you really want is a thread pool:

```
#include "threadpool.hpp"

int main()
{
    boost::threadpool::pool threadpool(8);  // I have 4 cpu's
                                            // Might be overkill need to time
                                            // to get exact numbers but depends on
                                            // blocking and other factors.

    for(int loop = 0;loop < 100000; ++loop)
    {
        // schedule 100,000 small tasks to be run in the 8 threads in the pool
        threadpool.schedule(task(loop));
    }

    // Destructor of threadpool
    // will force the main thread to wait
    // for all tasks to complete before exiting
}
```

Comment: Tested, Threadpool is faster but still it is 3 order of magnitude slower than native call.